# IBM Watson Assistant: Vary chatbot response by date/season

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I'm developing with IBM Watson Assistant and I want the response to vary by date (mainly so I can use seasonal jokes or change opening hours based on time of year from the `@sys-date` entity). I've built a test node and basically I need the intent to recognize `@sys-date: October` and respond one way that would differ if `@sys-date: August` has anyone had to vary the assistant's response based on the month? Is this even possible?

I have already tried `@sys-date: October` (System date is October) as the condition for the node (under "If Assistant Recognizes") and in date format but it never gets to that node. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can build chatbots with conditional responses. In Watson Assistant `@sys-date` is a system entity. It helps to detect dates in inputs. But if there is no date in the input text, then it would not have a value.

You could [use date / time functions](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-methods#dialog-methods-date-time) in a response and check for the current month. Use **if / then / else** for the answer of the month.